# Wit AI speech request with empty return

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp, wit-ai

I am trying to use wit ai speech endpoint with node.js but I receive an empty response

```
{
    "entities": {},
    "intents": [],
    "text": "",
    "traits": {}
}
```

When I use an audio that was recorded on my computer, I can get the text. But when I use an audio that was recorded on the browser, or in this case, obtained through **wpp connect api** (An API for receive and send whatsapp messages), the return is empty.

I have checked the audio and it has content.

Here is my code (But the error also happens in postman)

```
        await message.downloadMedia().then(data => {
            const binaryData = Buffer.from(data.data, 'base64')

            axios
            .post('https://api.wit.ai/speech?v=20230215', binaryData, {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
                'Content-Type': 'audio/ogg'
              },
              //data: dadosDoArquivo,
              responseType: 'json'
            })
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data) // Resposta da API
              console.log(response.status)
              const speechResponse = SpeechResponse.create(response.data)
              const chatMessageProps = {
                message: speechResponse.text,
                type: message.type,
                chatUser: chatUser
              }
              return ChatMessageInput.create(chatMessageProps)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error('Erro na requisição:', error)
            })
          })
```

And I have also tried to read write and read the file locally with `` fs.createReadStream(`audio7.ogg`) ``

Answer (score 0):

I´ve discovered that the problem is in the audio codec.
For it to work (at least with ogg format) needs to be with "Vorbis" codec.

I createad a function that converts the codec:

convertToVorbis(filename, callback) {
const inputFile = `${filename}.ogg`
const outputFile = `${filename}_converted.ogg`
ffmpeg(inputFile)
.audioCodec('libvorbis')
.on('end', function () {
console.log('Conversão finalizada.')
if (callback) callback(null, outputFile)
})
.on('error', function (err) {
console.error('Erro ao converter:', err)
if (callback) callback(err)
})
.save(outputFile)
}

**Important:** you need to instal ffmpeg because it runs on the terminal.